# `xdotools type` mangles carriage returns

Tags: command-line, scripting, x11, xdotool

I would like to setup a paste functionality allowing to paste copied text (like scripts and configuration files) to any kind of application, including virtual guests and remote sessions running graphical clients such as VNC (where a standard copy-paste is not possible).

To achieve this, I associated a shortcut in my desktop manager to the following command:

```
sh -c 'sleep 1; xdotool type -- "$(xsel -bo)"'
```

This works... but only for certain apps (and sadly VNC is not part of them, cruel world!).

- If I use this to paste the text into a `vi` running in `xterm` on the local host, then this works perfectly: the content of the file is preserved and written as expected. This also seem to work flawlessly in `gnome-terminal`.
- If `vi` runs in `xfce4-terminal` for instance still on the local host, all carriage returns are mangled.
- Similarly, if I try to paste to paste the text to any application (including `xterm`) through VNC, the text is correctly typed but here again all on a single line.

Where it becomes weird, it's that if I attach the following command to another keyboard shortcut:

```
sh -c 'sleep 1; xdotool key Return'
```

Here `xdotool` manages to input the carriage return in any application, so it is technically possible.

I tried to build on this as an ugly workaround to enforce the carriage return:

```
sh -c 'sleep 1; xsel -bo | { while read -r LINE; do xdotool type -- "$LINE"; xdotool key Return; done; }'
```

Now carriage return "works" this workaround now mangles the tabs and in all cases I don't like it as I won't always want the final carriage return (for instance when filling a web form field without immediately submitting it).

I think I have the same problem as [this guy](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/xdotool-users/oV40iJbLfJ8), but sadly the thread has no explanation.

Where is the problem? How can I make this work? Or if for some reason this is not possible is there another *lightweight* alternative for my initial need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For historical reasons, there are two characters that represent line breaks: line feed (commonly represented as LF, `\n`, `\012`, Ctrl+J, …) and carriage return (CR, `\r`, `\015`, Ctrl+M). Unix uses LF as the line terminator character, but keyboards send CR when you press <kbd>Return</kbd>. Some applications recognize a <kbd>Linefeed</kbd> key (which exists on some rare keyboards that weren't made for the PC market), but that's rare.

Experimentally, when there's a line break in the string, xdotool sends a <kbd>Linefeed</kbd> key. I'm not surprised that some applications don't recognize that. You can make it send <kbd>Return</kbd> instead by replacing the newlines with carriage returns.

```
sleep 1; xdotool type -- "$(xsel -bo | tr \\n \\r | sed s/\\r*\$//)"
```

Your workaround can also be made to work. Set `IFS` to an empty value, otherwise `read` strips off the leading and trailing whitespace on each line (that's why the tabs are disappearing). And don't send a <kbd>Return</kbd> after the last line. (This isn't strictly equivalent to the command substitution method: with a command substitution, all trailing empty lines are removed; with the following method, only the one final newline, if any, is ignored.)

```
sleep 1
xsel -bo | {
  IFS= read -r LINE;
  xdotool type -- "$LINE";
  while IFS= read -r LINE; do
    xdotool key Return;
    xdotool type -- "$LINE";
  done;
}
```

Note: I haven't tried anything in VNC, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thank you, I wouldn't figure out that *"keyboards send CR when you press 'Return'"*, I really like your one-liner which indeed works fine. I already came up with a solution similar to your second proposition, with an added `wid="$( xdotool getwindowfocus )"` line and `--window "$wid"` parameters added to `xdotools` commands so the resulting script won't potentially impact several windows on focus change, but the one-liner is clearly an improvement and now I understand the root cause!